# How to make highcharts default to 0 for missing data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a time series at a 1 minute interval. I would like to display that in a chart with missing points as 0.

I've found xAxis.ordinal and turned that off which displays the time series properly spaced out. The issue is that it draws lines between the points directly without going to 0 for the missing data.

Comment: Wraithan - did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Wraithan did you find a way to set missing points as 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is by pre-processing the data, replacing `null` with `0`:

```
var withNulls = [null, 12, 23, 45, 3.44, null, 0];
var noNulls = withNulls.map(function (item) {
    return (item === null) ? 0 : item;
});
```

Example saved on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7mhMP/

Comment: This does not answer the question, this just avoids the problem.

Comment: Example is not a time series on X, it is not a datetime value, but custom scale with any name, therefore it works. The problem arises when you have missing date-value pairs, so series are not continueous in datetime scale and graph line disappears.

Answer (score 6):

I've thorougly searched the [API reference of HighCharts](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts), but they don't offer that option. What they do offer is the option to disable the connection of points when `null` data is in between (only line and area charts):

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            connectNulls: false
        }
    }
});
```

This is the default setting according to the API, so I'm not sure why your data does connect with `null` values in between. Maybe they have changed the defaults lately?

[image: Example of HighChart with missing data]

I feel this is a good representation of your data, because defaulting `null` to `0` seems misleading.

Comment: The question asks for 0 replacement - no breaks, no null-connecting with averaged values in direct line from point to point. Missing value should be interpreted as 0. This is when we mean that no occations were observed, not that we missed the observation and don't know the value. We know the value is 0. Quite popular in database journals statistics.

Comment: The OP actually states that he would like to replace missing information with 0. He does not know it is 0. That is quite a difference.

Comment: Highs-forums also find it difficult to understand. To my mind "I would like to display that in a chart with missing points as 0" means that in my task missing points should be interpreted as 0. I want it 0, because I know it should be zero if abscent. In Highs the only assumption allowed is no-data-then-nulls, what is urgently needed is no-data-then-zeroes assumption.

Comment: I understand your point. Still I am really concerned about this. I really can't think of any situation where you want to _interpret_ missing data as 0.

Comment: It is quite popular. For example,you count your site events in a database: errors, logins etc. Of course, only happened events are written into log (journal). When you count events grouping by days, some days may have no events happened and they will be missed in dates sequence. This means 0 events observed. And if it were null, that would mean "no data - we didn't observe this day, we didn't count, no records, we don't know".

Answer (score 1):

You hava to fill the missed data as 0.
Because highchart don't konw xAxis interval.

If you have a time series at a 1 **minute** interval, you should set every missing **minute** data to 0;
If you have a time series at a 1 **day** interval, you should set every missing **day** data to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and what i understand is that you should set your data structure in database as VARCHAR and set the default value to null so where you don't have data it becomes NULL. Then it accept null values and highchart don't display and connect missing areas with `null` values.
In addition you have to receive data as `NULL` and don't change them to `''`.
see this working example:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        defaultSeriesType: 'spline', // use line or spline
        renderTo: 'container1'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [9, 4,null, 2, 1, 0, 6, 5, 4, 1, 6, 4]
    }]

});
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/2rNzr/) is the fiddle with two different chart using `null` and `''`

**UPDATE:**
If you are using parseINT to push data you should remember that `parseINT(NULL)` gives you `NAN` so for this bug try to manually push NULL with something like this:

```
var val = parseInt(rows[i]);
if (isNaN(val))
{
  val = null;
  result.push(val);
}
```