# How to show 0 for incomplete Series in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

My task is to display sale revenue data with highcharts. The user should be able to select the data by different "densities", (e.g. "hourly", "daily", "weekly", ...)

To clarify things I made up a simple jsfiddle, where you can see an example for density "monthly". As I do not have data in my database for every tick shown in the chart it looks "incomplete". (http://jsfiddle.net/em8J4/1/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: "spline"
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            min: 1335823200000,
            max: 1367359200000,
            tickInterval: 2592000000,
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [[1356994800000, 5],[1359673200000, 10], [1362092400000, 5], [1364767200000, 10]]
        }]
    });
});
```

Is there an easy way to set up highcharts to show a point with value 0 for ticks that do not have an associate data point given?

EDIT: Found a possible duplicated from 1 year ago which is still unanswered. Any ideas?
[How to make highcharts default to 0 for missing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395061/how-to-make-highcharts-default-to-0-for-missing-data)

Comment: My first thought was to iterate the ticks and if there's not point at that tick add a zero to the series.  BUT, your current data does not perfectly align with the ticks.  This becomes a more difficult task, of which ticks don't have points close to them.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I don't see that my data doesn't align with the ticks. But anyways it's probably easier to pre-process my data as @jilbrigs suggested...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is to pre-process your data yourself, and add 0 values for anything that is missing.

The chart has no way to determine what is missing, and what is meant to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Because you dont have specific categories, I'm afraid the best bet would be to add a value of "0" to your minimum / maximum value of the graph you set at min/max, before generating the Highcharts chart. For x-axis with categories this is less of an issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/dargno/kCT8R/

```
[1335823200000, 0],[1367359200000, 0]
```

Comment: That does not solve my problem. The idea is to show 0 for every tick that has no point associated in the data array. What I mean with "complete" [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/rrHsQ/1/).

Comment: Within Highcharts you can set a startdate and an interval, so you can just feed it the list of values. The only thing you need to build beforehand is the list where you fill in the blanks. This is not Highcharts-related, though you can create an array with 0 values from the startdate till the enddate, and fill that with the proper values where you have them.

Comment: Thanks Joris, you're right. I do pre-process my data now the way you suggested. Going to fill a new Array with values for every tick and taking the data from the database where I have them, otherwise set it to 0.

Comment: Hello I am also having the same requirement. Just curious to know if theres some new answer to the questions or we need to preprocess the data, which works fine. Is there any module or API within the highcharts to handle such a case.