# Highchart JS (HTML table, Line chart) line not showing if data has null value

Tags: html, highcharts

In Highchart JS API documentation, it shows that Line chart can be disconnected using null value.

```
  series: [{
    data: [29.9, null, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, null, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
  }]
```

(JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/minuteman/4cpsczdt/)

However if using HTML table, the line simply disappear. Only dots can be seen.

```
    <tr>
        <th>Plums</th>
        <td>null</td>
        <td>11</td>
    </tr>
```

(JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/minuteman/qrhp770m/)

How to make the line reappear using data from HTML table?

Comment: if you use null value answer will be same because of data point to null value which means you have no value on that point if you use "0" result will be different

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395061/how-to-make-highcharts-default-to-0-for-missing-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of that is parser which converts null to string instead of type null. The solution is use load event, iterate on each series / each point and correct values.

```
chart: {
      type: 'line',
      events: {
        load: function() {
        var chart = this,
                series = chart.series,
            each = Highcharts.each;

            each(series, function(serie, i) {
                each(serie.data, function(point,j){
                if(point.y === "null") {
                    point.update({
                    y: null
                  },false);
                }
              });
            });

            chart.redraw();
        }
      }
    },
```

Simple demo: jsfiddle.net/es7zrw71