# Consider 0 number of hits for omitted dates

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

In [this example](https://jsbin.com/coriyiqefe/4/edit?html,output), I draw a chart from 4 pairs of date and number of visits. I can change `dataGrouping.units` to `day` or `month` with `sum` as `approximation`.

For the dates that don't appear in `data`, I want to consider their number of visits is `0`. However, the current chart looks misleading.

One way to amend that is to prepare the data manually by myself, eg, by completing `data` by adding all the other dates with `0` as number of visits.

Does anyone know if HighCharts provides some parameters to customize this automatically? I tried `pointInterval` and `pointIntervalUnit`, it seems they have other purposes...

Comment: only way is to pre process the data. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395061/how-to-make-highcharts-default-to-0-for-missing-data

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to set `xAxis.ordinal` to `true`.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/hujdkL1L/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal